# How to use local git checkout for a go dependency for change tracking

Tags: git, go, dependency-management

I'm stuck with the following challenge:

While developing code, I would also like to develop a dependency (micromdm/scep) in parallel and track changes using git.

My code imports the library like this:

```
import(
    ...
    sscepclient "github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/client"
    "github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/cryptoutil/x509util"
    "github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/scep"
)
```

To point go to a locally chekced out version of the module, I replaced the module in my go.mod:

```
require (
...
github.com/micromdm/scep/v2 v2.0.0
)
replace github.com/micromdm/scep/v2 => /home/pi/go/scep
```

I did do a git clone on the repository of the scep module and can find the files in the directory specified with the replace directive.

But when I try to run my code, I get an error

```
../../scep/server/csrsigner.go:8:2: no required module provides package github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/scep; to add it:
        go get github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/scep
```

If I do go get the dependency as requested, I get the error message

```
go get: module github.com/micromdm/scep/v2@upgrade found (v2.0.0, replaced by /home/pi/go/scep), but does not contain package github.com/micromdm/scep/v2/scep
```

I also tried to add the replace statement in the dependency module's go.mod itself since the module also has several require statements that direct to the scep module, but without success.

From what I understand, GO is not able to find the modules (obviously) but to be honest, the handling of dependencies really confuses me. From what I found on the internet I understood that such a development of a locally checked-out repository should be possible by using the replace directive. I would be glad if someone could shed some light on this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Check if you have defined module version (v2)

   `module github.com/micromdm/scep/v2` @ `/home/pi/go/scep/go.mod`
2. **change the path to the module to be relative, in this case, it works**.

update 1: I see you did, but that only option I got in my mind.

update 2: found a small solution.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Where exactly should I state the relative path? I assume in the go.mod file in replace.

Now I have `replace github.com/micromdm/scep/v2 => ../scep` but still get the error 
`client.go:28:2: no required module provides package github.com/micromdm/scep/v2; to add it:
        go get github.com/micromdm/scep/v2`

Comment: You are right location for replacement is in `go.mod`. I was able to get this message only after I added an empty root package (_ "github.com/micromdm/scep/v2"), in case of sub packages (it was working). I have used your project for test, and it was within project I was working on if that's matter.

Comment: Ok, my bad. I missed a trailing "/scep" at the end of the import in my code. It works now using the relative path in go.mod. Thank you!